# How do I unwrap a list of list wrapped items in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a bean that resembles this:

```
public class Product {

    public String id;
    public String vendor;
    public Set<Image> images;
}

public class Image {

    public String originalSrc;
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize my JSON that resembles this:

```
{
  "id": "gid:\/\/mysite\/Product\/1853361520730",
  "vendor": "gadgetdown",
  "images": {
    "edges": [
      {
        "node": {
          "originalSrc": "https:\/\/cdn.something.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "node": {
          "originalSrc": "https:\/\/cdn.something.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I'm unable to deserialize the object as each of the `image` objects are wrapped in a `node` object and collectively in a `edges` object.

---

EDIT: For clarity, I don't want to accomplish this via using beans and this example is a simplification and all array items in the JSON payload are wrapped in this `edges` and `node` representation.

Comment: You can take a look on similar question [Jackson list deserialization. nested Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580856/jackson-list-deserialization-nested-lists). You can create `POJO` model which fits the structure or write custom deserialiser which will skip some entries. Another example: [Jackson deserialize JSON object field into single list property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708533/jackson-deserialize-json-object-field-into-single-list-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every list has a structure like below:

```
{
  "images": {
    "edges": [
      {
        "node": {
          "entry": "entry-value"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Each list is a `JSON Object` with `edges` property and each element in array is wrapped by `JSON Object` with `node` property. For this structure we can write generic deserializer similar to one from [Jackson - deserialize inner list of objects to list of one higher level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54424576/jackson-deserialize-inner-list-of-objects-to-list-of-one-higher-level) question.

Example `Set` deserialiser:

```
class InnerSetDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Set> implements ContextualDeserializer {

  private final JavaType propertyType;

  public InnerSetDeserializer() {
    this(null);
  }

  public InnerSetDeserializer(JavaType propertyType) {
    this.propertyType = propertyType;
  }

  @Override
  public Set deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
    p.nextToken(); // SKIP START_OBJECT
    p.nextToken(); // SKIP any FIELD_NAME

    CollectionType collectionType = getCollectionType(context);
    List<Map<String, Object>> list = context.readValue(p, collectionType);

    p.nextToken(); // SKIP END_OBJECT

    return list.stream().map(Map::values).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
  }

  private CollectionType getCollectionType(DeserializationContext context) {
    TypeFactory typeFactory = context.getTypeFactory();
    MapType mapType =
        typeFactory.constructMapType(
            Map.class, String.class, propertyType.getContentType().getRawClass());

    return typeFactory.constructCollectionType(List.class, mapType);
  }

  @Override
  public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext context, BeanProperty property) {
    return new InnerSetDeserializer(property.getType());
  }
}
```

We can use is as below:

```
class Product {

  private String id;
  private String vendor;

  @JsonDeserialize(using = InnerSetDeserializer.class)
  private Set<Image> images;

  // getters, setters
}
```

Example app:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ContextualDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.CollectionType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.MapType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class JsonApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File jsonFile = new File("./resources/test.json");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Product product = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Product.class);
    System.out.println(product);
  }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Product{id='gid://mysite/Product/1853361520730', vendor='gadgetdown', images=[Image{originalSrc='https://cdn.something.com'}, Image{originalSrc='https://cdn.something.com'}]}
```

Answer (score 3):

So `images` is not a `set` it is a `JSONObject` with `edges` list in it

```
public class Images {

   private List<Edge> edges;

    }
```

Each `Edge` contains `Node` object,

```
public class Edge {

   private Node node;

   }
```

Each `Node` has single String property `originalSrc`

```
public class Node  {

 private String originalSrc;

  }
```

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't verbose enough. Please see my edit. Thank you.

Comment: so you don't want java beans, then how so you want to accomplish this? by using `JSONObject` and `JSONArray`? @MridangAgarwalla

Answer (score 0):

To unwrap `Image`s out of `"node": { "originalSrc": "https:\/\/cdn.something.com" }` you can simply use `@JsonRootName` annotation

```
@JsonRootName(value = "node")
class Image {
    public String originalSrc;
}
```

But unwrapping images collection out of `"images": { "edges": [{...}, {...}] }` is bit more complex, need to use custom `JsonDeserializer`

```
class Product {
    public String id;
    public String vendor;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = ImageSetDeserializer.class)
    public Set<Image> images;
}


class ImageSetDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Set<Image>> {
    public Set<Image> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jsonParser.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jsonParser);
        return mapper.convertValue(node.get("edges").findValues("node"), new TypeReference<Set<Image>>() {});
    }
}
```

Finally a test:

```
public class ProductTest {

    private final String source = "{\n" +
            "  \"id\": \"gid:\\/\\/mysite\\/Product\\/1853361520730\",\n" +
            "  \"vendor\": \"gadgetdown\",\n" +
            "  \"images\": {\n" +
            "    \"edges\": [\n" +
            "      {\n" +
            "        \"node\": {\n" +
            "          \"originalSrc\": \"https:\\/\\/cdn.something.com\"\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "      },\n" +
            "      {\n" +
            "        \"node\": {\n" +
            "          \"originalSrc\": \"https:\\/\\/cdn.something.com\"\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    ]\n" +
            "  }" +
            "}";

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Product product = mapper.readValue(source, Product.class);

        assertEquals(product.id, "gid://mysite/Product/1853361520730");
        assertEquals(product.vendor, "gadgetdown");
        assertNotNull(product.images);
        List<Image> images = new ArrayList<>(product.images);
        assertEquals(images.size(), 2);
        assertEquals(images.get(0).originalSrc, "https://cdn.something.com");
        assertEquals(images.get(1).originalSrc, "https://cdn.something.com");
    }
}
```