# Java Spring web - convert sub-property to object with validator

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-validator, spring-json

I'm using spring web with controllers services models and validation.
I have a Color object and a Color service.

```
@Data
public class Color {
    private String name;
    private long value;
    private int rating;
}
```

In one of my controllers, I'm accepting an object:

```
public class NewEventRequest {
  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 5, max = 30)
  private String eventName;

  /* @ValidColor */
  private Color eventColor;
  // private String eventColor;
}
```

As you can see, the `eventColor` sub-property is of type `Color`. However, I want the sender to be able to send just the color name (there aren't many colors and they're cached in memory anyway).

I know I can use a color of type string and validators to make sure that color exist, but is there a way to also then cast it to Color?

Comment: You can use [Bean Validation](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation) or [Spring Validation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation) with custom constraints. Take a look at: [@Valid when creating objects with jackson without controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55457754/valid-when-creating-objects-with-jackson-without-controller), [Spring MVC: How to perform validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146298/spring-mvc-how-to-perform-validation)

Comment: @MichałZiober yeah I'm aware, that is what "@ValidColor" can do. But even if I do that, it will just validate the incoming string - good or bad - it won't convert it into a Color structure.

Comment: To convert types you can use `Converter<IN, OUT>` interface. Take a look on this example: [Jackson deserialize JSON object field into single list property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708533/jackson-deserialize-json-object-field-into-single-list-property)

Comment: @MichałZiober great that is what I was looking for! Post it as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `JSON` payload does not fit `Java` model you need to implement custom deserialiser or [Converter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/Converter.html) interface. Take a look at this example:

- [Jackson deserialize JSON object field into single list property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708533/jackson-deserialize-json-object-field-into-single-list-property)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Enum types instead of string? like as:

```java
public enum ColorName {
    Red, Yellow, Blue, ...
}

@Data
public class Color {
    private ColorName name;
    private long value;
    private int rating;
}
```

I don't know whether I understand what you mean correctly,
but it could contain values Only you defined. So you don't even need to validate the values.

Comment: That wouldn't help anyway - there still need to be a custom conversion between the incoming string and the color. Either way the data is editable at runtime, so I can't use enum as well